# JavaScript not load image before first display

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I suppose this question may have been already asked. I'm building a photos slider in JavaScript and my images being mostly high quality photos, I would like to load the photos only when they are displayed.

```
<div class="wrap-button">
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div class="grid fade">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-portrait"><img src="./photos/au1/IMG_0267.jpg" alt="arbre jungle"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-landscape"><img src="./photos/au1/IMG_0726.jpg" alt="plage heaven on earth"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-landscape"><img src="./photos/au1/IMG_0763.jpg" alt="route jusque l'horizon"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-portrait"><img src="./photos/au1/IMG_9969.jpg" alt="arbre géant dans la jungle"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-landscape"><img src="./photos/au1/IMG_0847.jpg" alt="vache morte sur la route désertique"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-landscape"><img src="./photos/au1/IMG_9582.jpg" alt="architecture dans un parc sydney"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using a JavaScript function in an external file to show or hide the slides. The images are organized by [mansonry.js](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjrzLem4svYAhWEkeAKHfrKAfkQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmasonry.desandro.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw3GAVAzkce9xVlSsjJShXGh) and an external CSS file.

```
if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
}

if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
}

for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
}

slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {$grid.masonry(masonryOptions)});
```

Comment: there are a lot of Lazy-Load plugins for JS, personally, I use Unveil: https://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Comment: The problem is at the page loading. There is maybe 60 img on 8 sliders, creating a huge page loading time. I wonder if the display:none is efficient enough even with a JS plugin to do not load the over sliders at the first page loading.

Comment: No. Display none still downloads the images. Lazy-loading requires you to change the html as well, for example using data-src and replace `data-src` with `src` before the image comes into screen.

Comment: Thanks for the advice,all is working fine now !